# Process.Start fails with access denied

Tags: c#, .net, windows, security

I want to launch a child process from a .NET application (.NET 4.8) that has access only to a single specific directory on the disk. To achieve this, we first impersonate with a restricted access token where we remove all SIDs from the token except for a single group. This group has read & write access to the specific directory on the disk and nothing else. Then we try to start the child process.

Unfortunately, when trying to start the process it fails with a very generic "access denied" error. My guess is, that I need some sort of special access rights to even start a process. What are the minimum requirements for that? What else could be hindering me from starting the process?

Note: The process itself resides within this special directory, so that should not be the problem.

Comment: Read access to ``%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\``, ``%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\`` and the exe folder?

Comment: The child process is not a .NET Application. Also when looking at it with procmon it is not even yet running, so it must be something during process startup or even before. It tries to access System.dll in the GAC with access denied in procmon, maybe that's the reason...but I can't think of a reason why it would want to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Our team just updated to Net5.0 and we're having similar issues trying to open a logging directory from `Process.Start("path\to\log");` If anyone has some insight, that would be awesome.